# Find a certain difference between members of a list (or set) of numbers

Tags: python

my first question, so please be gentle, I hope I get the formatting right :) I think the question is self explaining. I am looking for a better/faster way to find a difference in a set of numbers... maybe I want a tolerance with it. All I came up with is:

```
 def difference(numbers,diff,tol):
    '''diff is the searched difference,numbers is a list \
    of numbers and tol the tolerance'''
    numbers.sort()
    match=set()
    for i in numbers:
        low = i+diff-tol
        high= i+diff+tol
        for k in numbers:
                if k > high:
                    break
                if k < low:
                    continue
                match.add(i)
                match.add(k)
    return match
```

But I bet there are way better ways to achieve the result.

Any idea is welcome,

Christian

Comment: *"the question is self explaining"* – it wouldn't hurt to clarify what exactly you mean when you say "difference between members of a list"…

Comment: I can't seem to understand anything in this "self-explanatory question".

Comment: It was not clear for me too. What do you mean with "tolerance" and "diff" parameters?

Comment: Sample I/O (actual vs desired) could go a long way here in aiding understainding

Comment: That's a rather odd output format. Are you sure you want to have all numbers in the result set which are a part of a found difference?

Comment: @wnnmaw And it would be helpful for testing alternative solutions...

Comment: @felipsmartins Sorry for not being clear enough here. diff is the numerical difference searched and tolerance the offset of the difference. For example I may search for a difference of 5 +/- 0.1  in the list of provided numbers, resulting in anything matching from 4.9 to 5.1. So if I have 13 and 18.1 in my list, they would be picked out as they create a difference of 5.1 - (5 within the tolerance of 0.1)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Agreed. The output could be as well a list with tuples of the matches. I was more wondering if there is a faster way than iterating twice over the list. Jean-François Fabre already improved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid running the lowest part of the numbers in the second loop (no need for `low`, just check numbers ahead)

With that you can drop the `set` and use a `list` instead: less hashing, less processing. Also, don't change the `numbers` input by sorting it, the caller may not expect it. Use a locally sorted list instead (the other advantage is that `numbers` can now be a `set`, a `deque` ...:

```
def difference(numbers,diff,tol):
    '''diff is the searched difference,numbers is a list
    of numbers and tol the tolerance'''
    snum = sorted(numbers)
    match=list()
    for i,n in enumerate(snum):
        high= n+diff+tol
        for j in range(i+1,len(snum)):
                k = snum[j]
                if k > high:
                    break
                match.append(n)
                match.append(k)
    return match
```

(maybe that would be a better question for code review, the boundary is thin)

Comment: Thank you for the constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
    count    = len(numbers)
    numbers1 = numbers[:count - 1]
    numbers2 = numbers[1:]

    for i in range(0, count - 1):
        dif = numbers2[i] - numbers1[i]
        if abs(dif) <= tol:
            match.add(numbers1[i])
            match.add(numbers2[i])
```

Comment: Please consider to upvote the answer which was useful for you.